# font-family firefox child elements don't inherit, while chrome works correctly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I noticed a strange bug in firefox.

Fonts set on parent element, never cascade to child elements. If I set font directly to child element all works fine in FF.

I don't observe same behavior in chrome.

Any thoughts? is this expected known? Or maybe I've some other bug...

Comment: No one can say without seeing your code.

Comment: Very well could be a bug. Would need to see your code however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing comma,

in

```
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif
```

instead of

```
font-family: 'Lato' sans-serif
```

Comment: I suppose this marks at as solved.